# Macro variable is not expanded if directly followed by chars that form a valid identifier

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

Given a preprocessor macro like

```
#define DECLARE(NAME) \
    int NAME;         \
    int NAME_2
```

`Name_2` denotes a new identifier. Is it possible to expand `Name`, so that

```
DECLARE(x);
```

becomes

```
int x;
int x_2;
```

Comment: NAME##_2 might work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `##` glue:

```
#define DECLARE(NAME) \
   int NAME;         \
   int NAME##_2
```

Comment: Caveat to the solution is that if `NAME` is itself a macro, it will not be expanded in the second expanded line, where as it would get expanded in the first line.

Answer (score 3):

The final line of your macro could be

```
int NAME##_2
```

which would do it. `##` *concatenates* tokens.